# Visualize logical order with div-Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for a `Javascript`-Library/`jQuery-AddIn` or Helper script in *general* to position a chain of divs in a logical order. i.e.:

```
A  --- > B
^  --- > C ---> D  ---> E
|                       |   
-------------------------
```

Imagine those letters are `div`s containing some other elements as well. The goal would be to pass in the the order and the `html` Elements and the positioning would be automatic.

Does someone know a component for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `jsPlump` which can handle this specific task. It's an Library for `jQuery`, `MooTools` and `YUI3` and you can download it [here](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/anchorDemo.html#).